# how to move strings up and down and remove similar ones from them?

Tags: r

I asked a question which was not that clear probably. so I try to explain it in a understandable way. This is my data

My data looks like this

It looks like this

```
#             V1      V2               V3
#1                 Q9UNZ5             Q9Y2W1
#2 Q9ULV4;Q6QEF8                     
#3                                    Q9UNZ5
#4                  Q9H6F5              
#5                  Q9H2K0     Q9ULV4;Q6QEF8
#6                  Q9GZZ1            Q9UKD2
#7        Q9H6F5    Q9GZZ1            Q9GZZ1
#8        Q9GZZ1                      Q9NYF8
#9        Q9BWS9
```

I want to remove the duplicated strings across all of them 
for example, the V1 we have all the strings for the first time, so we don't remove anything just arrange them to have

```
Q9ULV4
Q6QEF8
Q9H6F5
Q9GZZ1 
Q9BWS9
```

Then we check the second columns strings with the first column and we remove those that are repeated and again arrange them. for the third column we check the strings with the first and the second , if similar then we remove and then arrange them. So the output should look like below.

```
Q9ULV4  Q9UNZ5  Q9Y2W1
Q6QEF8  Q9H2K0  Q9UKD2
Q9H6F5          Q9NYF8
Q9GZZ1          
Q9BWS9
```

It is not similar to any questions I have asked; so please if it is still not clear, just comment, I try to explain it

Comment: @akrun sorry I was not online, Yes it is a mistake that I did (typo) I corrected my question

Comment: @akrun you are right! however I have only one vote and I liked his answer because he or she put time on this answer so I just wanted to appreciate his/her time! otherwise I accept the more efficient with less package use and fast answer which probably is the one with 4 votes :-)

Comment: @docendodiscimus I picked it with good intentions to make sure that the OP update his post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line converts `df` to a list `L`.  The second line creates a long form data frame `long` containing the values in column1 and the `df` column names in column 2 as a factor.  Making it a factor is needed as the levels preserve all column names including the ones that are subsequently eliminated due to only containing duplicates.  Also, it preserves the order of the column names.  The last line removes duplicates producing `long0`.  No packages are used.

```
L <- lapply(df,  function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";")))
long <- transform(stack(L), ind = factor(as.character(ind), levels = names(df)))
long0 <- subset(long, !duplicated(values))
```

Now we consider three possible forms of output:

**1) long form data frame**

```
> long0
   values ind
1  Q9ULV4  V1
2  Q6QEF8  V1
3  Q9H6F5  V1
4  Q9GZZ1  V1
5  Q9BWS9  V1
6  Q9UNZ5  V2
8  Q9H2K0  V2
11 Q9Y2W1  V3
15 Q9UKD2  V3
17 Q9NYF8  V3
```

**2) list**

```
L0 <- unstack(long0)
```

giving:

```
> L0
$V1
[1] "Q9ULV4" "Q6QEF8" "Q9H6F5" "Q9GZZ1" "Q9BWS9"

$V2
[1] "Q9UNZ5" "Q9H2K0"

$V3
[1] "Q9Y2W1" "Q9UKD2" "Q9NYF8"
```

**3) character matrix**   Create a version of `L0` that replaces each zero length component with `NA` and then expand the length of each component to the maximum length reforming into a matrix at the same time via `sapply`.

```
lens <- lengths(L0)
m0 <- sapply(replace(L0, !lens, NA), "length<-", max(lens))
```

giving:

```
> m0
     V1       V2       V3      
[1,] "Q9ULV4" "Q9UNZ5" "Q9Y2W1"
[2,] "Q6QEF8" "Q9H2K0" "Q9UKD2"
[3,] "Q9H6F5" NA       "Q9NYF8"
[4,] "Q9GZZ1" NA       NA      
[5,] "Q9BWS9" NA       NA
```

**Update:** Some fixes and clarifications.

**Note 1:** The input `df` in reproducible form is:

```
df <-
structure(list(V1 = c("", "Q9ULV4;Q6QEF8", "", "", "", "", "Q9H6F5", 
"Q9GZZ1", "Q9BWS9"), V2 = c("Q9UNZ5", "", "", "Q9H6F5", "Q9H2K0", 
"Q9GZZ1", "Q9GZZ1", "", ""), V3 = c("Q9Y2W1", "", "Q9UNZ5", "", 
"Q9ULV4;Q6QEF8", "Q9UKD2", "Q9GZZ1", "Q9NYF8", "")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Note 2:** In the most recent development version of R, "R Under development (unstable) (2016-07-05 r70861)", the `long <-` line near the top could be simplified to just `long <- stack(L)` since `stack` creates a factor with all levels in that version of R.

Comment: is it possible to remove the "" around each string ? I already liked your answer , thanks

Comment: There are no quotes in the strings themselves.  The quotes are just the way R represents the output on the console.  If this is still important to you try `noquote(L0)` and `noquote(m0)`.

Comment: when I do this on my real data, I get error m0 <- do.call(cbind, lapply(L0, as.ts))[TRUE, ]
Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations, also do you think it is correct to do this to have blank instead NA m0[is.na(m0)] <- " "

Comment: thanks now It works L0 <- lapply(L0, function(x) if (length(x)) x else "") , once again thanks and I accepted your answer THANKS

Comment: that is great thanks! I will check it out now, one question if I don't want to remove duplicated but arrange them, I just remove the !duplicated ?

Comment: Yes, use `long` and `L` in place of `long0` and `L0` if duplicates removal not needed.  Some additional improvements have been made.

Comment: thank you so much bro, I don't know how to thank you , you spent so much time on this, thanks . I have posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38062420/select-specific-columns-based-on-part-of-strings-from-the-column-name-and-order if you have any idea , please don't hesitate to let me know

Answer (score 5):

I would approach this in two steps:

1) get unique elements per column and convert to list:

```
l <- lapply(df, function(x) unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";"))))
```

2) remove duplicates that appear in any previous columns

```
for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  l[[i]] <- setdiff(l[[i]], unlist(l[seq_len(i-1L)]))
}
```

The reason why I use a `list` instead of a `data.frame` is because `data.frame`s require all columns to have the same number of rows, which is not the case here (unless you fill them with NA or empty strings). In such cases, a `list` structure is the way to go.

Comment: discus thanks, I liked your answer however, I prefer not to use loop if there is alternative as below

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in plain R based on the `duplicate` function in this way:

```
lst <- lapply(df, function(x) unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";", fixed = TRUE)))
cols <- colnames(df)
seen_entries <- NULL

for (i in (1:ncol(df))) { 
  n_seen_before <- length(seen_entries)
  seen_entries <- c(seen_entries, lst[[cols[i]]])
  lst[[cols[i]]] <- lst[[cols[i]]][(!duplicated(seen_entries))[
                                        (n_seen_before+1):length(seen_entries)]]
}
```

Output is:

```
> lst
$V1
[1] "Q9ULV4" "Q6QEF8" "Q9H6F5" "Q9GZZ1" "Q9BWS9"

$V2
[1] "Q9UNZ5" "Q9H2K0"

$V3
[1] "Q9Y2W1" "Q9UKD2" "Q9NYF8"
```

Probably there are more elegant solution using e.g. `data.table` or something similar.

Comment: thanks patrik I liked your answer but it uses a loop

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
lst <- lapply(df, function(x) unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ";"))))
lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
            v1 <- unlist(lst[seq(i)])
            setdiff(lst[[i]], v1[duplicated(v1)])})
#[[1]]
#[1] "Q9ULV4" "Q6QEF8" "Q9H6F5" "Q9GZZ1" "Q9BWS9"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Q9UNZ5" "Q9H2K0"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Q9Y2W1" "Q9UKD2" "Q9NYF8"
```