# Sort strings based on number in part of string

Tags: r

I have a huge data that I cannot upload here because.

I have two types of columns, their names start with `T.H.L` or `T.H.L.varies....`. Both types have are numbered in the format `So####`, e.g.,   `T.H.L.So1_P1_A2` until `T.H.L.So10000_P1_A2`.

For each T.H.L column there is a column named `T.H.L.varies....` with the same ending.

I want to order the columns by the numbers after `So`, with first the `T.H.L` and then the corresponding `T.H.L.varies....` version for each `So` number.

What I tried was to do

```
library(gtools) 
mySorted<- df2[,mixedorder(colnames(df2))]
```

Which is close, it sorts them correctly by number, but first all `T.H.L` and then all `T.H.L.varies` instead of alternating them.

I have posted the column names to Github:

Comment: This is all about column names. Rather sharing any of your data frame rows, just share `dput(names(df))`, or maybe `dput(names(df)[1:100])` if the first is too long.

Comment: Also try `df2 = df[, grep(pattern = "^T\\.H\\.L\\.", x = names(df))]`... it might be what you want. If that's not what you want, maybe you can clarify, the sentence *"Means I want one T.H.L and one T.H.L.varies which both have the same end"* doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Gregor I shared it above on github because I could not put it here

Comment: @Gregor if you look at the dput of names that I sent, it is shown that I have as many T.H.L as T.H.L.varies, one , now is clear ?

Comment: Maybe more so. You *already have* the columns you want, and your only problem is sorting them? Is this correct? And you want them sorted by the number following the letters `So` in the column name?

Comment: @Gregor Yes that is exactly what I want. You can even modify my question if you think it is confusing.Please look at the very end of my question. you can see the example order I gave in my question

Comment: I edited the question, I think it is much clearer now. I don't have time to write up a solution right now, but if it is still unanswered when I get home from work I will do it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's call the names of your data frame (the names you want to reorder) `x`:

```
x = names(df2)

# first remove the ones without numbers
# because we want to use the numbers for ordering
no_numbers = c("T.H.L", "T.H.L.varies....")
x = x[! x %in% no_numbers]

# now extract the numbers so we can order them
library(stringr)
x_num = as.numeric(str_extract(string = x, pattern = "(?<=So)[0-9]+"))

# calculate the order first by number, then alphabetically to break ties
ord = order(x_num, x)

# verify it is working
head(c(no_numbers, x[ord]), 10)
#  [1] "T.H.L"                      "T.H.L.varies...."           "T.H.L.So1_P1_A1"           
#  [4] "T.H.L.varies.....So1_P1_A1" "T.H.L.So2_P1_A2"            "T.H.L.varies.....So2_P1_A2"
#  [7] "T.H.L.So3_P1_A3"            "T.H.L.varies.....So3_P1_A3" "T.H.L.So4_P1_A4"           
# [10] "T.H.L.varies.....So4_P1_A4"

# finally, reorder your data frame columns
df2 = df2[, c(no_numbers, x[ord])]
```

And you should be done.

Comment: Maybe you could share `dput(head(names(x), 10))`? It works when I read in your github post, made it a character vector and called it `x`.

Comment: dput(head(x, 10))? because dput(head(names(x), 10)) gives me NULL

Comment: Yeah, `dput(head(names(df2), 10))` maybe

Comment: I found where the problem is "(?<=So)[0-9]+" this is not matching with my real characters name  The real column names are Ratio.H.L.  and Ratio.H.L.variability....   Ratio.H.L.Mo1.... etc

Comment: It's regex. `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits, `(?<=So)` says look before those digits for the characters `"So"`, but don't include them in the extract. It works fine on the data I read in from github... as you can see. That output I show is real output based on the input you posted on github,

Comment: Well, in all your examples the numbers start with `So`, so I used `"So"`. In your `dput`, the numbers begin with `Mo`, so you should replace the `S` in my code with `M`.

Comment: Also, the `T.H.L` should be replaced with `Ratio.H.L`, apparently.

Comment: thank you so much!! I liked your answer, I accepted it and I will like some of your answer because you helped me a lot , thanks